# Have query return column horizontally

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table in SQL Server which stores a list of questions and answers from a survey on our website.  It's a pretty standard layout, here's how it stores the completed surveys:

```
Name          Question                        Answer
James Smith   What is your address?           23 Duck Ln.
James Smith   How old are you?                48
James Smith   Do you have a job?              yes
Sarah Murphy  What is your address?           44 West St.
Sarah Murphy  How old are you?                23
Sarah Murphy  Do you have a job?              no
Jack Western  What is your address?           PO Box 17
Jack Western  Do you have a job?              yes
```

As you can see, it's hard to read the data once a few surveys are completed.  I need to have the values returned horizontally, with a person each having only one row the first column containing the person's name, with the other rows each containing a question as the header, and the answer under it.  Here's how the query should return values:

```
Name          What is your address?    How old are you?    Do you have a job?
James Smith   23 Duck Ln.              48                  yes
Sarah Murphy  44 West St.              23                  no
Jack Western  PO Box 17                                    yes
```

Is this possible?  By the way, I am only posting a few of the questions - it becomes much larger if there are 10+ questions asked on the site.

Thanks for your help!

Edit:

Please don't focus on whether or not the records should be parsed in the application layer.  I ultimately want to use the output in R, which isn't even designed to handle large datasets.

Comment: No, that's how your application should display the values. The database's job is to store and retrieve data, not format it for display. Do this transformation in your application code, not SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to perform this in SQL since you are using SQL Server you can use the PIVOT function to transform the data from rows to columns:

```
select name,
  [What is your address?], 
  [How old are you?], 
  [Do you have a job?]
from yourtable
pivot
(
  max(answer)
  for question in ([What is your address?], [How old are you?], [Do you have a job?])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5eef/1).

If you have an unknown values, then you can use dynamic SQL to get the solution:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Question) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT name, ' + @cols + ' 
             from yourtable
            pivot 
            (
                max(answer)
                for Question in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5eef/3)

Comment: Voted up - great answer.  I also was not aware of SQL Fiddle until now, thanks for this learning resource!